# How to optimize a decision in a CFD C code

Tags: c, performance, function-pointers

I want to optimize the use of different functions in a [CFD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics) code, which the user can choose at runtime via a config file which is read by the program.

I came up with a minimal working example, where there are two separate functions with one input. One squares the input and one cubes it. Via command line option the user can choose which function to use. The code the squares/cubes a bunch of numbers (it calculates the integral from 0 to 1 of either x^2 or x^3, depending which function was chosen) in a for loop and outputs the results. The first variant is just a switch case in a for loop (case1). The second thing I tries was a function pointer, which is set before the loop (case2). The third thing I did was selectively compiling only the function that the user intends to use with the use of preprocessor commands (case3).

case1:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

double f_square(double x) {return x * x;}

double f_cube(double x) {return x * x * x;}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double x;
    double sum = 0;
    double del_x = 4e-10;

    printf("Speed test -- no optimisation\n");

    clock_t startClock = clock();
    for (x = 0; x < 1; x += del_x) {
        switch (argv[1][0]) {
        case '2':
            sum += f_square(x) * del_x;
            break;
        case '3':
            sum += f_cube(x) * del_x;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid choice! Abort\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    clock_t endClock = clock();

    printf("Int_{0}^{1} x^%c: %.8g\n", argv[1][0], sum);
    printf("Execution time: %.6f\n", (endClock - startClock) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

case2:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

double f_square(double x) {return x * x;}

double f_cube(double x) {return x * x * x;}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double x;
    double sum = 0;
    double del_x = 4e-10;
    double (*f)(double);

    printf("Speed test -- function pointers\n");

    switch (argv[1][0]) {
    case '2':
        f = &f_square;
        break;
    case '3':
        f = &f_cube;
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid choice! Abort\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    clock_t startClock = clock();
    for (x = 0; x < 1; x += del_x) {
        sum += f(x) * del_x;
    }
    clock_t endClock = clock();

    printf("Int_{0}^{1} x^%c: %.8g\n", argv[1][0], sum);
    printf("Execution time: %.6f\n", (endClock - startClock) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

case3:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef SQUARE
double f(double x) {return x * x;}
#endif

#ifdef CUBE
double f(double x) {return x * x * x;}
#endif

int main(void)
{
    double x;
    double sum = 0;
    double del_x = 4e-10;

    printf("Speed test -- selective compilation\n");

    clock_t startClock = clock();
    for (x = 0; x < 1; x += del_x) {
        sum += f(x) * del_x;
    }
    clock_t endClock = clock();

    #ifdef SQUARE
    printf("Int_{0}^{1} x^2: %.8g\n", sum);
    #endif
    #ifdef CUBE
    printf("Int_{0}^{1} x^3: %.8g\n", sum);
    #endif
    printf("Execution time: %.6f\n", (endClock - startClock) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

When measuring the execution times I found something odd:

- with O0 I got the distribution I expected, case3 was the fastest, followed by case2 and then case1
- with O1--O3 case2 always performed significantly worse than case1 and  case3

Here are some images comparing the execution times

- [Compiled with O0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jspk9.png)
- [Compiled with O1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cdVI.png)
- [Compiled with O3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWLDz.png).

This confuses me and I would like to know what I can do in order to use function pointers without losing performance, because for flexibility reasons I really want to use function pointers.

=> Why are function pointers so slow?

I want to add that I am not a software engineer but rather an aerospace engineering student and sadly we do not get a lot of programming lessons,
so every little detail might be helpful.

Comment: The issue with pointers to functions is that concrete function is not known at compile time. Such a knowledge about specific function at compile time allows for compiler to make optimizations (I would guess that for O3 option compiler parallelized computations by using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD feature of CPU). You might try to use `c++` with its templates, which are compile time polymorphism

Comment: With -O3, the compiler may also be inlining the function calls -- this generally can't be done with function pointers, as the actual code of the function being called can't be known ahead of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a disassembly view of two implementations of similar functions: https://c.godbolt.org/z/l24Zhl

Note that with -O2, the first method inlines the calls to `f_cube` and `f_square` (note no calls to the functions in the assembly), but the second version does not.

Most likely, the first version is then further sped-up due to [Branch Prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) on the processor.

Have you profiled your code and found that this area is a bottleneck? Remember that you make the greatest speed gains by optimizing the most-used code first. Remember: first make it work, then make it fast.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So the main thing seems to be the inlining of the function, which is not happening when I use function pointers. Also, I have not profiled my code yet, because it not yet finshed... But I will definately do that once I have a functioning version. Is inlining always faster, or does it depend on the size of the function and the amount of iterations in the for loop. And what about while loops?

Comment: Generally the compiler is pretty smart about deciding when to inline functions, usually based on their assembly length. The amount of iterations of the for loop shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: If you want to still use function pointers and get some of the performance benefits of static dispatch (ie your method1), consider keeping the dynamic dispatch in the level above the for loop - so each implementation of the method has its own for loop. This way you'll only have to pay the penalty of the dynamic dispatch once before the loop starts instead of every iteration of the loop, and you give back the compiler's ability to inline the function call into the loop.

Comment: Here's a good video that describes some of the things that happen on the low-level CPU side that you can exploit to make code run faster in some situations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BP6NxVxDQIs. Keep in mind though that optimizations like this should only be considered after you've done all the other stuff, like reducing the algorighmic complexity of your functions, etc.

Comment: Ahh so then I would just move the for into the functions and then I still get the inling benefits, or rather I am inlining it myself. I think I will try to never call a function pointer inside a loop but rather move the loop into the function and call the function pointer instead. Thanks for the video, that is some powerful knowledge for when the code is finished! I will definitely have a go at those optimization strategies :)